# How to Render Line Numbers with Document in AvalonEdit?

Tags: printing, numbers, line, avalonedit

Is there a way to render line numbers in the left margin along with the AvalonEdit TextEditor document?

Answer (score 4):

if used as wpf controller, add

```
ShowLineNumbers="True"
```

to the avalonedit tag